# Ayuda para correr Gulp

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, servidor, gulp

Hola estoy creando un proyecto con node.js y quiero correr Gulp, que me actualiza todos los cambios realizados en el código, css, server, etc.,
No se si sabre formular bien la pregunta y si debería mostrar mas código para que puedan ayudarme.

Pero me da un error y no pasa Gulp, por lo que no puedo actualizar los cambios y no puedo seguir adelante con el proyecto.
Tengo puesto para que pase Gulp cuando corro el servidor, pero el servidor corre pero gulp no. Tampoco me funciona correr npm run build.
Muestro mi código y el error por si pudieran ayudarme, llevo días estancado.
Gracias.

> assert.js:42   throw new errors.AssertionError({   ^
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
>       at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\victor\CURSOS\JAVASCRIPT-NODE\PROYECTO
>   MICHAELGRAM\michaelgram\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
>       at Gulp.task (C:\Users\victor\CURSOS\JAVASCRIPT-NODE\PROYECTO MICHAELGRAM\michaelgram\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\victor\CURSOS\JAVASCRIPT-NODE\PROYECTO
>   MICHAELGRAM\michaelgram\gulpfile.js:125:6)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! michaelgram@0.1.0 build: `gulp` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the michaelgram@0.1.0 build
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

**package.jon**

```
{
  "name": "michaelgram",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Programa para compartir fotos con tus amigos",
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "Curso",
    "definitivo",
    "de",
    "javascript",
    "de",
    "Platzi"
  ],
  "author": "Miguel Espeso",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.239.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "empty-element": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "file-extension": "^4.0.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "intl-messageformat": "^2.2.0",
    "intl-relativeformat": "^2.1.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "multer-s3": "^2.7.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.9.1",
    "page": "^1.8.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "michaelgram-client": "file:../michaelgram-client",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "readable-stream": "^2.3.6",
    "superagent": "^3.8.3",
    "title": "^3.2.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "yo-yo": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.2.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "start": "concurrently \"gulp watch\" \"node server.js\""
  }
}
```

**Archivo del Servidor**

```
let express = require('express');
let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let multer  = require('multer');
let multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
let ext = require('file-extension');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let expressSession = require('express-session');
let passport = require('passport');
let michaelgram = require('michaelgram-client')
let config = require('./config');
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let client = michaelgram.createClient(config.client);

let s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey
});

let storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: 'michaelgram',
  acl: 'public-read',
  metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname })
  },
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, +Date.now() + '.' + ext(file.originalname))
  }
});


let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('picture');

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: config.secret,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram' });
})

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signup' });
})

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
  let user = req.body;
  client.saveUser(user, function (err, usr) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)

    res.redirect('/signin');
  });
});

app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signin' });
})

app.get('/api/pictures', function (req, res, next) {
  let pictures = [
    {
      user: {
        username: 'miguelito',
        avatar: 'https://i1.wp.com/www.sopitas.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/escorpiones.jpg?fit=860%2C484'
      },
      url: 'office.jpg',
      likes: 0,
      liked: false,
      createdAt: newDate().getTime()
    },
    {
      user: {
        username: 'miguelito',
        avatar: 'https://i1.wp.com/www.sopitas.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/escorpiones.jpg?fit=860%2C484'
      },
      url: 'office.jpg',
      likes: 1,
      liked: true,
      createdAt: newDate().setDate(newDate().getDate() - 10)
    }
  ];

  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send(pictures);
  }, 2000)
});

app.post('/api/pictures', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(500, "Error uploading file");
    }
    res.send('File uploaded');
  })
})

app.get('/api/user/:username', (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    username: 'miguelito',
  }

  res.send(user);
})

app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
})

app.get('/:username/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
})

app.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) returnconsole.log('Hubo un error'), process.exit(1);

  console.log('Michaelgram escuchando en el puerto 3000');
})
```

**Archivo gulpfile.js**

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');
let babel = require('babelify');
let browserify = require('browserify');
let source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
let watchify = require('watchify');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  gulp
    .src('index.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

gulp.task('assets', function () {
  gulp
    .src('assets/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

functioncompile(watch) {
  let bundle = browserify('./src/index.js', {debug: true});

  if (watch) {
    bundle = watchify(bundle);
    bundle.on('update', function () {
      console.log('--> Bundling...');
      rebundle();
    });
  }

  functionrebundle() {
    bundle
      .transform(babel, { presets: [ 'es2015' ], plugins: [ 'syntax-async-functions', 'transform-regenerator' ] })
      .bundle()
      .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err); this.emit('end') })
      .pipe(source('index.js'))
      .pipe(rename('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
  }

  rebundle();
}

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return compile();
});

gulp.task('watch', function () { return compile(true); });

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'assets', 'build']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La forma de ejecutar tareas en serie o paralelo es diferente en Gulp 4.

La ejecución de una serie de tareas hazla de la siguiente forma:

```
var default = gulp.series('styles', 'assets', 'build');
gulp.task('default', default );
```

Y si quisieras hacerlo en paralelo y luego el build, podrías hacer:

```
var default = gulp.series(gulp.parallel('styles', 'assets'),'build');
gulp.task('default',default );
```

Comment: Gracias, @Federico Madoery. He cambiado la ultima linea 
por la que tu me propones:`gulp.task('default', gulp.series('styles', 'assets', 'build'));` y corren default y styles, pero Gulp me sigue sin correr, me da el siguiente error...

Comment: `[21:18:09] Using gulpfile ~\CURSOS\JAVASCRIPT-NODE\PROYECTO MICHAELGRAM\michaelgram\gulpfile.js
[21:18:09] Starting 'default'...
[21:18:09] Starting 'styles'...
[21:18:09] The following tasks did not complete: default, styles
[21:18:09] Did you forget to signal async completion?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! michaelgram@0.1.0 build: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!

Comment: Prueba con esta forma, debería de ser lo mismo, pero en algunos casos así es mejor.

Comment: ¿ Cual, he probado las dos y la de abajo da error. La primera que pones  corre, pero falta de correr gulp

Comment: Las dos hacen lo mismo, en diferente orden de ejecución, solo tenia mal el nombre de una de las funciónes que llama. "falta de correr gulp" Gulp corre esas tareas, así que me parece que te confundes. Por otro lado lo que falte ejecutar es tema de tu implementacion, a modo de ejemplo puse las tres tareas que intentabas ejecutar en serie.

Comment: De la manera que lo pusiste ahora, tiene errores de sintaxis, no está bien escrito, no admite var default el editor, y menos al correr en consola, voy a hacer cambios a ver si doy con ello.

Comment: Finalmente funciono con la primera opcion, ahora tengo otro problema.